# Google cloud, how connect php on vm with remote PostgreSQL database?

Tags: php, postgresql, cloud, instance, google-cloud-sql

I have a Virtual Machine with Ubuntu server wirh apache, I want connect my php page with a remote PostgreSQL database but this dont work. But I tried in my localhost and it worked.

```
<?php
$inf = "host='IP_POSTGRES' port='5432' dbname='bd' user='user' 
password='pssw'";
$con = pg_connect($inf) or die("Connection Error".pg_last_error());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

where exactly is your postgre server, Cloud? Does ping from your pc to server ip works? Does the server running on the cloud has some mac filtering?

Can you just make sure with these questions

Comment: I have the postgreSQL in other account whit an instance SQL- PostgreSQL9.6. Yes the ping works on the VM, im not sure if the vm has a mac filter.

Comment: If VM network adapter setting has NAT option, then you can directly use 'localhost' in host='IP_POSTGRES.(or) if you hav bridged adapter option enabled then you should give the VM ip address. And make sure that in bridged adapter option your host ip and vm ip are in same family ip